# Printing specific result of WooCommerce function as shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show the result of a WooCommerce add on function (Total Store Credit) in the sidebar. This function looks at a user, adds up the value of all coupons they have available to use in the store, and then prints the total. I am only interested in showing the total available credit in the sidebar.

If I am looking at the code correctly, `$total_store_credit` is a variable in the function `sc_endpoint_content()`

My newbie brain is struggling with what the next step is here. I would like to simply return whatever $total_store_credit is as a shortcode in functions.php so I can stick it wherever, but I'm not entirely sure how I would do that.

Would something like this be on the right track?:

```
add_shortcode('total_credit', 'get_total_credit');

function get_total_credit ($total_store_credit){
    get_sc_endpoint_content();
}
```

After this (if this is even right) I really got stuck.

Any feedback would be very helpful!

Comment: You should add in your question the source code from `get_sc_endpoint_content()` please, as nobody can guess what this function does. Without it your question appear to be off topic for different reasons.

Comment: I would usually expect a function which begins with "get_" to return a value, so try simply making the line `return get_sc_endpoint_content();`